# An Inequality Involving $a/(b + c) + b/(a + c) + c/(a + b)$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

While looking for an explanation to the first inequality, I spied another similar inequality. So, I will ask about both of them here.

$a$, $b$, and $c$ are positive numbers.
$$\frac{a}{b + c} + \frac{b}{a + c} + \frac{c}{a + b}
\geq \frac{(a + b + c)^{2}}{2(ab + ac + bc)}.$$
$$\frac{a^{2}}{b} + \frac{b^{2}}{c} + \frac{c^{2}}{a}
\geq \frac{(a + b + c)^{2}}{a + b + c} = a + b + c.$$

If the second inequality is an application of the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, state for me the two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ that are used to justify it.

Comment: The second inequality is true due to [a special case of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality known as Sedrakyan's inequality, Engel's form, or Titu's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedrakyan%27s_inequality).

Comment: For the first inequality, try multiplying and dividing $a,b,c$ respectively for the three terms and apply the second inequality

Comment: @VTand dito for the first inequality

Answer (score 0):

I'm just elaborating the hints given in the comments. For the second equality, take $v= (a/\sqrt{b}, b/\sqrt{c},c/\sqrt{a})$ and $w = (\sqrt{b},\sqrt{c},\sqrt{a})$. By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$|\langle v,w \rangle|^{2} = (a+b+c)^{2} \le ||v||^{2}||w||^{2} = (a+b+c)\bigg{(}\frac{a^{2}}{b}+\frac{b^{2}}{c}+\frac{c^{2}}{a}\bigg{)}$$
from where the inequality follows.

For the first inequality, rewrite the left hand side as:
$$\frac{a^{2}}{ab+ac} + \frac{b^{2}}{ab+bc} + \frac{c^{2}}{ac+bc}$$
and use the second inequality:
$$\frac{a^{2}}{ab+ac} + \frac{b^{2}}{ab+bc} + \frac{c^{2}}{ac+bc} \ge \frac{(a+b+c)^{2}}{ab+ac+ab+bc+ac+bc} = \frac{(a+b+c)^{2}}{2(ab+bc+ac)}$$
as desired.

Comment: In the last line you use something stronger than the second inequality, because the second inequality of the OP is Titu restricted to the case where the variables in the denominator are a cyclical permutation of the square roots of the numerator.

Answer (score 0):

There's something called [Titu's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedrakyan%27s_inequality) which gives you both. The second one is more direct, so let me prove only the first one.

Take $n=3$, $a_1=a, a_2=b, a_3=c$, and $b_1=a(b+c), b_2=b(a+c), b_3=c(a+b)$ and apply the mentioned Inequality to get
$$\frac{a^2}{a(b + c)} + \frac{b^2}{b(a + c)} + \frac{c^2}{c(a + b)} \geq \frac{(a + b + c)^{2}}{a(b + c)+b(a + c)+c(a + b)}=\frac{(a + b + c)^{2}}{2(ab+bc+ca)}$$
which completes the proof.